# visual studio 2013 Professional could not open new project

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Whenever I try to create a new project in VS 2013 I get the error:

> New project/item dialog could not be initialized due to error:
>   Exception of type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Dialogs.DialogInitializationException' was
>   thrown.

I Tried this :

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio 2010
2. Go to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE" (depend of VS installation directory)
3. Shift + R Click : Open Command Window Here
4. Run command: WDExpress.exe /resetuserdata

But this giving me error :
[Error while trying above steps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aFqw.png)

Comment: Try running command prompt as administrator - you can also try a repair from control panel, programs & features,

Comment: Have tried  try a repair from control panel, programs & features. And also  re-installed.